# PHP Session timeout code with warning

Tags: php, session, settimeout

I want to add session time out in my PHP website. I Google and got below link 
[Timeout Dialog code using Jquery](http://rigoneri.github.io/timeout-dialog.js/)

I'm not able to figureout how to implement that in my PHP. Please guide me how to add code in my website. I want user to logout automatically if page is idle for more than 15mins

Answer (score 0):

You have to update php.ini in session.gc_maxlifetime configuration 
example for session time out to 24 minutes:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440
```

Warning : it is not automatic to destroy the session after this number of seconds, it depends of the probability of garbage collection
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is is a setting in php.ini.

For controlling the lifetime of the session cookie:
http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

To make the session info for garbage collection there is:
http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

The second one will not necessarily destroy the session after that period of time, it depends when the GC will need the space and try to free it.

Basically the session cookie will expire.